# Pandas giving IndexError on one dataframe but not on another similar dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting the error:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

When trying to do:

```
df.loc[df["DATE"] == "xxx"].index[0]
```

On this csv-file:

```
DATE,x,y
123,5,7
```

But it works perfectly fine on this csv-file:

```
Date,X,Y
1991-07-09,123,123
```

Why?

xxx is changed out to 123 and 1991-07-09 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DATE,x,y
123,5,7
```

123 is a `int64`, while you're looking to match a `str`

`df.loc[df["DATE"] == 123].index[0]`: **works** without quotes

```
Date,X,Y
1991-07-09,123,123
```

1991-07-09 is an `object` or `datetime64[ns]`

`df.loc[df["Date"] == "1991-07-09"].index[0]`: **works** with quotes

Comment: `dtypes` can be checked using `df.info()`...glad to help

Comment: The more you know! It was such a stupid issue, and I know I tried comparing it to an int but since I wasn't sure that was the problem I let it go and tried a bunch of useless solutions. Turns out that the function I wrote didn't just type-hint, it also casted the int to a str... Hindsight is 20/20 and you made my life a bunch easier, thanks again.